# Error: querySrv ESERVFAIL _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.yalzkc2.mongodb.net

Tags: mongodb, cpanel, nodejs-server

I am tryping to deploey a MERN project on cpanel. Everything working fine on my localhost, but getting this error in my "stderr.log" log.

1. I tried to restart the server again.
2. Allowed access from anywhere on my atlas

Answer (score 0):

hey i found the solution!!
i solved the issue by edit my connection string ---->
"mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.yalzkc2.mongodb.net/" this as -------------->
"mongodb://username:password@ac-5jfoqgk-shard-00-00.yalzkc2.mongodb.net:27017,ac-5jfoqgk-shard-00-01.yalzkc2.mongodb.net:27017,ac-5jfoqgk-shard-00-02.yalzkc2.mongodb.net:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-lfxg2j-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority"

**You can do this by going to your atlas**

- step 1- sign in to your atlas account
- step 2- click on "Database" under 'Deployment' section
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/615rf.png)
- step 3- click on "Connect"
- step-4- Click on drivers section
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SsyB.png)
- step-5- change the version of the 'Nodejs' driver to '2.2.12 OR later'
- step-6- Now copy the string

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymtvx.png)

**AND YOUR PROBLEM IS SOLVED**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).